# Google Chart API - Line Chart: Averaging data

Tags: python, google-visualization, average

I have data that maps across ~4 years on a line chart:

`0 72 346 172 193 240 34 24 18 26 25 34 52 104 23 34 29 32 55 46 44 25 36 45 48 60 65 69 66 24 28 39 2 72 74 65 69 44 66 57 49 35 77 49 32 63 47 79 47`

the line chart seems to limit you to 100 max value, so some of my values are 'off the chart'. I figure they want you calculate your data in such a way that my max value (in my case, 346) equal 100 and then to average out everything in-between. It makes sense as Google Chart API allows floating numbers.

Im just not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you had your numbers in a list l - you could do the following to scale the numbers to a percentage of the max value:

```
[ float(i) * 100 / max(l) for i in l ]
```

Then if you want to get back the original value from a value n:

```
n / 100 * max(l)
```